# Is phase angle a important thing to consider when designing filters?

Tags: filter, phase-shift

Whenever I was choosing values for filters I always ignored the phase angle plots, but should I be taking it into consideration when for example designing a high-pass filter for the input of an amplifier or a low-pass filter in the feedback network? What are the situations where it's important to know the phase angle and take it into consideration in the design?

Comment: What does the signal represent? If it's audio then there are sonic implications - i.e. you will be changing how the audio sounds.

Comment: Stability is a concern and in audio you might get a hearable lag between frequency components which where at the same time in the unfiltered signal.

Comment: Your question is soliciting opinion - read the rules.

Comment: This isn't as much opinion-based as rather broad. The answer is: it depends on the application [of the filter]. LvW gave you some decent examples when it does matter.

Comment: For contrast, here's a well-known example when [it isn't](https://books.google.com/books?id=7djSyLcX4coC&pg=PA16): the [Linkwitz–Riley (4th order) filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkwitz%E2%80%93Riley_filter) widely used in audio.

Answer (score 4):

From system theory we know that the negative slope of the phase response gives the so called "group delay" of the filter. For some applications - e.g. filtering of squarewave signals - we want to have a group delay as constant as possible (identical to a linear phase response) in order to retain the original waveform (in spite of filtering).

This requirement was the reason to define the Thomson/Bessel response as one of the standard filter functions. As an another example: We have allpass filters (constant magnitude over frequency) with the only purpose to shape/correct the phase response (resp. group delay) of other filter ciruits (Delay equalizer).